# GCE cannot access private SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sql, vpc

I tried to access from GCE instance to Cloud SQL instance, which is private and having private service connection.

following private services access docs, I setup VPC and FW, and create SQL and GCE in same VPC.
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access

but in GCE, ping to SQL instance, nor sql connection didn't work.

1. create VPC

> gcloud compute networks create test-custom-vpc --subnet-mode=custom --bgp-routing-mode=global  --mtu=1460

2. create subnet

> gcloud compute networks subnets create vpc-sb-1 --network=test-custom-vpc --range=10.100.0.0/16 --region=asia-northeast1

3. create IP range for private service connection

> gcloud compute addresses create vpc-peering-range --global --purpose=VPC_PEERING 
> --addresses=192.168.0.0 --prefix-length=16 --description=description --network=test-custom-vpc

4. create VPC peering for SQL

> gcloud services vpc-peerings connect --service=servicenetworking.googleapis.com --ranges=vpc-peering-range --network=test-custom-vpc --project=my-project

5. create mySQL in VPC

> gcloud --project=my-project beta sql instances create vpc-sql-1 --network=test-custom-vpc --no-assign-ip

6. create GCE instance in VPC

> gcloud compute instances create vm-in-sb-1 --subnet vpc-sb-1 --zone asia-northeast1-b

7. create FW rule, so far allow all IP/protocol

> gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-all --network test-custom-vpc --direction ingress --action allow --rules all

---

Then, I would access VM with ssh and check connection between VM & SQL

> gcloud sql instances list
> NAME       DATABASE_VERSION  LOCATION       TIER              PRIMARY_ADDRESS  PRIVATE_ADDRESS  STATUS
> vpc-sql-1  MYSQL_5_7         us-central1-b  db-n1-standard-1  -                192.168.0.3      RUNNABLE

-> SQL private IP is `192.168.0.3`

8. ssh login

> gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "asia-northeast1-b" "vm-in-sb-1" --project "my-project"

9. check connection

> ping 192.168.0.3

no response

> psql -h 192.168.0.3 -U postgres

> mysql --host=192.168.0.3 --user=root --password

psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
Is the server running on host "192.168.0.3" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

---

I have no idea what configuration is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your case, all configuration are working well but please note, using the command below in **step #5** will create a Cloud SQL instance for **Mysql** not for Postgres:

```
gcloud --project=my-project beta sql instances create vpc-sql-1 --network=test-custom-vpc --no-assign-ip
```

If you want to create a Cloud SQL instance for **Postgres** use the command below:

```
gcloud --project=my-project beta sql instances create vpc-sql-1 --database-version=POSTGRES_12 --cpu=2 --memory=7680MB --network=test-custom-vpc --no-assign-ip
```

The problem is you are connecting to Cloud SQL for Mysql using Postgres database client. To proper connect use the following example:

**for Mysql example:**

```
mysql --host=192.168.0.3 --user=root --password
```

**for Postgres example:**

```
psql -h 192.168.0.3 -U postgres
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
the command `psql -h 192.168.0.3 -U postgres` was not correct. I tried `mysql --host=192.168.0.3 --user=root --password` but still failed

Comment: sorry for my confusing update. Before I must have got error even if I had use mySQL or postgressSQL, but now, I cloud  connect mysql. I don't know the reason, but possibly I might select different SQL. Thank you so much